# Apple's clang can't use <=> with std::tuple

Tags: c++, clang, stdtuple, spaceship-operator

The following compiles fine with GCC and clang on on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/98W7xvnse), but on my MacBook, in Xcode 14 it dies:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <compare>
#include <tuple>

using std::cout; using std::tuple; using std::endl;

int main() {
    tuple<float, float> tuplee = {1.0,2.0};
    tuple<float, float> tuploo = {3.0,4.0};
    cout << (tuplee < tuploo) << endl;
    auto res = (tuplee <=> tuploo);
    cout << (res < 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> invalid operands to binary expression ('std::tuple<float, float>' and 'std::tuple<float, float>')

It points to the `<=>` on the tuples. Do you think it's a bug in Apple's clang, or am I missing something?

Command line on my MacBook:

```
% clang++ --version          
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
% clang++ -std=c++2b main.cpp
main.cpp:11:21: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('tuple<float, float>' and 'tuple<float, float>')
    cout << (tuplee <=> tuploo) << endl;
             ~~~~~~ ^   ~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What version of clang ? Fails with 13.0.1 compiles with 14.0.0 - live (change the version) - https://godbolt.org/z/83Y39znxr

Comment: Also make sure you have the `-std=c++20` option enabled.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's odd, I tried it with godbolt clang 13.0.1, and it worked. That's because I was only passing the `-std=c++20` flag. If I take your example and drop the `-stdlib=libc++` flag, then it works with 13.0.1. I'm not sure why that flag is affecting it. I didn't think there was more than one stdlib to choose from.

Comment: stdlibc++ and libc++ are the two main open source versions of the standard library.  libstdc++ usually ships with GCC and libc++ usually ships with Clang.

Comment: Updated question to show clang version I'm using locally.

Comment: It isn’t just a matter of which Standard Library implementation you choose — it has _everything_ to do with the selected language version. Not only do new revisions add new powers to the language, they can _change_ the behavior of stuff in older versions. Hence, implementations must pay attention to make sure things work properly for the selected version. AFAIK, GCC’s current lib won’t support anything older than C++14.

Comment: I don’t code on a Mac but from what I’ve heard it’s advised to not use apple clang and to install clang from homebrew

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Apple clang with clib++ (from xcode) appears broken in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug. The bug was fixed in llvm ([relevant change](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/b80f2dfd11e2d73852f9f4fc96700fc6517e4e81#diff-7e94e704b9fd05c9fb5fc4c8b4eaefa19afa3abf993aebfc1b9609678d4b5c9a)). But by checking the tuple header in Macos SDK, one can find apple do not implement <=> for tuple.

The bug also affects arm64 variants of Macos. Clang version on my mac:

```
➜  test clang --version                                  
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

PS. Homebrew llvm@14 compiles fine. Just do not use apple clang

Comment: Has this bug been solved in Apple-Clang 15 ? :)